# Axe devtools throwing unnecessary violations

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, semantics, axedevtools

So I have this navigation bar with the following structure:

[click for code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKBph.png)

I am following the same structure that is present in https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubar/examples/menubar-navigation/
(standard for accessibility)

However when I run Axe devtools it throws the following errors:

- Certain Aria roles must contain particular children

  - Ensures elements with an ARIA role that require child roles contain them
  - To solve this problem, you need to fix at least (1) of the following:
    - Element has children which are not allowed: [role=none]
    - Element uses aria-busy="true" while showing a loader
- Certain aria roles must be contained by particular parents (**showing the error for span element**)

  - Ensures elements with an ARIA role that require parent roles are contained by them

    - Required ARIA parents role not present: menu, menubar, group

When I run axe devtools in w3.org site it throws no such error. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. I am following the same semantic structure as mentioned in the site. The only difference I can see that I have a span element. Is that's what's causing the issue?
And why is role none not allowed when its the same in w3.org site. I am not able to find much info in this topic. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason axe-core is throwing the error is due [presentational role conflict](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#conflict_resolution_presentation_none). Essentially any element that has a global ARIA attribute or is focusable *must* be made available to assistive technologies. Since `role=presentation` and `role=none` would remove the element from assistive technologies, they instead completely ignore the role and use the element's implicit role as if the `role` attribute wasn't there.

Because of this, the last `li` in your list which has the `aria-labelledby` attribute (which is a global ARIA attribute) is not presentational, so the menu contains a child that it doesn't support (`listitem`), and the `menuitem` of the `li` has a parent it doesn't allow (`listitem` again).